# (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' ([Errno 2] No such file or directory)

Tags: python, mysql

i can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' of my database on phpMyadmin with mamp.my code if :

```
def connectDB(self):
    char = str("%")
    self.connection = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',
    unix_socket='/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql.sock',
    user="root",
    passwd="root",
    database="Casino",
    charset='utf8mb4',
    cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
    return self.connection
```

how to solve it?

Comment: did you check if the socket file actually exist?

Comment: yes i checked it exists